# Is it worth to create one partion filling whole disk on Linux?

Tags: linux, diskmanagement

Let imagine that we have a disk. The whole disk is going to be use for one mount point or LVM physical volume. Is there a point to create separate partition covering the whole disk? Or maybe put filesystem directly on disk?

Answer (score 0):

There are some utilities that are less than pleased if the disk has no partition table, but if you'll be using it as one volume, you can just format the device directly.

What do you think you'll lose if you don't ?

Comment: I prefer to have only necessary layers of software. Recently I've dived depper into I/O performance and started to wonder I got (or lost) anything with and without partition table, in situation where the whole disk was assigned to one partition. BTW  When I was working with a lot of VMs I made LVM directly onto a 'disk' and put everything on it. I didn't have any problem, but wonder if it possible was just a luck.